# ReactJS - why is function for removing array duplicates causes dropdown list to malfunction

Tags: json, reactjs, api

I have a page written in react JS that populates three dropdown list with data; the data is pulled from a json file. One dropdown displays the client's names, another displays the building site name, and the last one displays the segment name.

The client and segments dropdown were displaying duplicate data, so I implemented a function to resolve the issue. However, the building site name dropdown list, which was displaying the building list name now only displays one building name (actually, the last building name from the json file), when other building names exists.

What am getting stuck on is, why is the building site name being affected, I only needed to remove the duplicates from the other two dropdown list.

sample json file/ array:
https://api.myjson.com/bins/file

This is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Ast extends Component {

   constructor(){
       super();
       this.state = {
           data: [],
           cfmRateFactor: "10",
       };
   } //end constructor

   change = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
}; //end change


removeDuplicates(arr) {
    const map = new Map();
    arr.forEach(v => map.set(v.clientName, v)) 
    return [...map.values()];
  }

   componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/16pjuq', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        /*body: JSON.stringify({
            username: '{userName}',
            password: '{password}'
        })*/
    }) /*end fetch */
    .then(results => results.json()) 
    .then(data => this.setState({ data: this.removeDuplicates(data) }));   


}//end life cycle

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
            <div>

                <div className="container">
                    <div className="astContainer">
                        <form>
                            <div>
                                <h2>Memeber Selection:</h2>

                                    {['clientName', 'siteName', 'segmentName'].map(key => (
                                        <div className="dropdown-padding">
                                        <select key={key}  className="custom-select">
                                        {this.state.data.map(({ [key]: value }) => <option key={value}>{value}</option>)}
                                        </select> 
                                        </div>
                                    ))}

                            </div>
                            <div className="txt_cfm">
                                        <label for="example-text-input">Modify CFM Rate Factor:</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="textbox"  id="cfmRateFactor" name="cfmRateFactor" value={this.state.cfmRateFactor} onChange={e => this.change(e) } />
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                    <div>
                                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                        </div> 
                                </div>     
                            </form>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>


        );
      }
}

export default Ast
```

Could I get some help as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reducing your data set to items that have a unique `clientName`. Based on your data set above, both have `"clientName": "Fairfax CPS-VA-02-14 - TK"` so you're only keeping the last one.

**Edit**: After the comments below, maybe this will help explain why there's only on building name. Here's how I read through what `removeDuplicates` is doing:

- the `arr` argument is something like:

  ```
  [
      {
          "siteName": "Alan Leis Instructional Center",
          "clientName": "Fairfax CPS-VA-02-14 - TK",
          "segmentName": "Daniels Run ES New Chiller 4-7-2017-04-30-2018~25313~Daniels Run ES RTU Area Calibration~37851~Mod",
      },
      {
          "siteName": "Aldrin Elementary School",
          "clientName": "Fairfax CPS-VA-02-14 - TK",
          "segmentName": "Daniels Run ES New Chiller 4-7-2017-04-30-2018~25313~Daniels Run ES Calibration~52310~Mod",
      }
  ]
  ```
- `map` is assigned to a `new Map`
- the `forEach` method is called on `arr`

  - `v` is assigned to be the first element of `arr`

    ```
    {
        "siteName": "Alan Leis Instructional Center",
        "clientName": "Fairfax CPS-VA-02-14 - TK",
        "segmentName": "Daniels Run ES New Chiller 4-7-2017-04-30-2018~253 13~Daniels Run ES RTU Area Calibration~37851~Mod",
    },
    ```
  - `map.set` is called to store `v` with the key `v.clientName`. The `map` is now a `Map` with an internal structure like `{ "Fairfax CPS-VA-02-14 - TK": arr[0] }`
  - **In the next iteration**:
    `v` is the 1st element of `arr`

    ```
    {
        "siteName": "Aldrin Elementary School",
        "clientName": "Fairfax CPS-VA-02-14 - TK",
        "segmentName": "Daniels Run ES New Chiller 4-7-2017-04-30-2018~25313~Daniels Run ES Calibration~52310~Mod",
    }
    ```
  - `map.set` is called to store `v` with the key `v.clientName`. **This overwrites the previous value**. The `map` is now a `Map` with an internal structure like `{ "Fairfax CPS-VA-02-14 - TK": arr[1] }`
  - And on until there are no more elements
- The call to `map.values()` will get the values for each key/value pair, but there is only one in the map which has an internal state like: `{ "Fairfax CPS-VA-02-14 - TK": arr[arr.length - 1] }`
- The value(s) are put into a new array that is the equivalent of `[arr[arr.length-1]]`
- The new array is returned with only one value

Comment: yes all the datasets have the same client name, but what I fail to understand is why is the building site dropdown only displaying one item when there are several other buildings with different names; I'm aiming at getting all the building names to populate the respective dropdown. I was only expecting the function to affect the client and segment name drop-downs. is there something am doing wrong in the way am implementing my function?

Comment: How many values do you have in your Map in removeDuplicates? If you only have one clientName in all your data, do you only have one value? Have a look at what `map.set` is doing.

Comment: currently, I only have the value clientName in the function, I only get the one client name in the dropdown, which is what I want; but, the building names are not the same, so I still do not understand why am only now getting 1 building name. ...Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain what's happening in that function. If that doesn't help, add a breakpoint in the function and step through what's happening.

Comment: Did that help @user1724708?